# "return" and "try-catch-finally" block evaluation in scala

Tags: scala

The following two code generate different result:

```
def x = try{
  true
} finally false
```

invoke x gets `true`

```
def y:Boolean = try{
  return true
} finally {
  return false
}
```

invoke y gets `false`

the `return` version behave same as Java.

Personally I never use 'return' in scala. But it's good to know how scala evaluate the value of a try-catch-finally block. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701793/behaviour-of-return-statement-in-catch-and-finally) have a return statement in a finally block (even though it is technically allowed, at least in Java, C# for example forbids it).

If the Scala finally block had an implicit return, that would always clobber the intended return value. So that makes no sense.

But I suppose it cannot help you if you explicitly write it that way.

Comment: But what is "an implicit return" ?

Comment: "Implicit return": Maybe the wrong word, but what I meant is that Scala uses the result of the last line in the code block as the return value for the block.

Comment: Thilo is right. Putting a `return` statement in a `finally` block should be considered a mistake, and actually not allowed. `Finally` is to clean up stuff no matter whether the method body succeeds or throws an exception. It's not the place to decide a return value! Therefore, the body of the `finally` clause is taken to evaluate to `Unit`. In your first example, the `false` is implicitly converted to `Unit`.

Comment: So the conclusion is: Never use `return` in a `finally` block and in Scala the body of `finally` has no effect on the evaluation of the whole try-catch-finally expression. Sciss make this answer complete.

Answer (score 10):

According to the Scala language spec:

> A try expression try { b } finally e evaluates the block b. If evaluation of b
>   does not cause an exception to be thrown, the expression e is evaluated. If an exception
>   is thrown during evaluation of e, the evaluation of the try expression is aborted
>   with the thrown exception. If no exception is thrown during evaluation of e, the
>   result of b is returned as the result of the try expression.

This behaviour would seem to be in contradiction with that spec. I would guess that, since 'return' causes an immediate return from the *function*, this results in overriding the standard behaviour for a try block. An illuminating example is:

```
def z : Boolean = {
  val foo = try { true } finally { return false }
  true
}
```

Invoking `z` returns `false`.

Comment: Yes, returning from a finally block breaks flow control. It should be forbidden.

Comment: `return` always breaks flow control. It only gets especially weird in that case.

Comment: It's according to the spec. The following paragraph says that the type of `e` is expected to conform to `Unit`, meaning `e` is evaluated only for its side-effects. When `e` is `return ..`, the evaluation rules say that the control flow leaves the currently executed method, returning the given argument.