# Returning a value from try - finally

Tags: scala

Why does `method1`  return 1 while `method2` 2:

```
def method1 = try { 1 } finally { 2 }                  

def method2: Int = try { return 1 } finally { return 2 }
```

and why does `method2` require specifying its return type?

Comment: This looks like it is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443743/return-and-try-catch-finally-block-evaluation-in-scala

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892985/return-value-of-finally-block-in-scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question will probably be closed by morning, but just for fun:

```
scala> def foo = return 1
<console>:7: error: method foo has return statement; needs result type
       def foo = return 1
                 ^
```

SLS 6.20: "The type of a return expression is scala.Nothing."

That answers the second question. It doesn't assist result type inference.