# 'finally block does not complete normally' Eclipse warning

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

Eclipse give me that warning in the following code:

```
public int getTicket(int lotteryId, String player) {
    try {
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + this.hostname + ":" + this.port + "/" + this.database, this.user, this.password); 
        int ticketNumber;

        PreparedStatement p = c.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT max(num_ticket) " +
                "FROM loteria_tickets " +
                "WHERE id_loteria = ?"
                );
        p.setInt(1, lotteryId);
        ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            ticketNumber = rs.getInt(1);
        } else {
            ticketNumber = -1;
        }

        ticketNumber++;

        p = c.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO loteria_tickets " +
                "VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        p.setInt(1, lotteryId);
        p.setInt(2, ticketNumber);
        p.setString(3, player);
        p.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date((new java.util.Date()).getTime()));
        p.executeUpdate();

        return ticketNumber;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally { 
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                c.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: remove return -1 ; and it should be fine

Comment: @Dennis 'finally block does not complete normally'  he has written this in subject line

Comment: Add return -1 after the try-catch-finally block.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

remove return statement from it.
Final block is considered to be cleanup block, return is not generally expected in it.

Comment: I see, i should have the return at the end of the catch... Thanks

Comment: But is there any harm? if I do this consciously, understanding the repercussions?

Comment: I think OP wanted to return -1 when something went wrong, in the original post -1 is _always_ returned...

Answer (score 32):

The `return` from `finally` "overrides" further exception throwing.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(f());
    }
    public static int f() {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        } finally {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

> > 1

Answer (score 15):

Generally a `finally` block should never have a return statement because it would overwrite other `return`-statements or `Exceptions`.

For further reading and more detailed answers to the backgrounds of it please see the question

[Behaviour of return statement in catch and finally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701793/behaviour-of-return-statement-in-catch-and-finally)

Answer (score 5):

With both `return` and `throw` statement in the `finally` bloc you will get the warning, for example, you will get the same warning with the following finally block:

```
...
}finally{
        throw new RuntimeException("from finally!");
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any `catch` blocks, then your `finally` blocks have to be nested directly inside of each other. It's only catching an exception that allows your code to continue past the end of a try/catch/finally block. If you don't catch the exception, you can't have any code after a finally block!

You can see how this works [with this example on Repl.it](https://repl.it/@bradparks/TastyFocusedDos)

### Example Output

```
testing if 0 > 5 ?
try1
try2
finally3
catch1
finally2
After other finally
finally1
end of function

testing if 10 > 5 ?
try1
try2
try3
success
finally3
finally2
finally1
```

#### Code in example at Repl.it

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        isGreaterThan5(0);
        isGreaterThan5(10);
    }

    public static boolean isGreaterThan5(int a)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("testing if " + a + " > 5 ?");
        try
        {
            System.out.println("try1");
            try
            {
                System.out.println("try2");
                try
                {
                    if (a <= 5)
                    {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Problems!");
                    }

                    System.out.println("try3");

                    System.out.println("success");
                    return true;
                }
                finally
                {
                    System.out.println("finally3");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("catch1");
            }
            finally
            {
                System.out.println("finally2");
            }
            System.out.println("After other finally");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("failed");
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("finally1");
        }

        System.out.println("end of function");
        return false;
    }

}
```