# return statement - finally block does not complete normally

Tags: java, eclipse, try-catch-finally

Similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481251/finally-block-does-not-complete-normally-eclipse-warning). But that does not provide answer.

```
try {
        object = (Dev)Class.forName("Dev").newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Devis not available");
    }
    finally
    {
        return object;  
    }
```

But **finally** block gives warning :

> finally block does not complete normally

But as per my understating, **finally** block always gets executed and will return the object. Why warning says that it will not get completed normally?

Comment: Because the definition of your object is in try block which may or may not complete as expected. Hence.

Comment: @Ritikesh In that case finally will return null. But it will get executed.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18205628/2817802) answer might be useful

Comment: Also have a look at these questions: [Multiple returns: Which one sets the final return value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309964/multiple-returns-which-one-sets-the-final-return-value) and [try catch finally return, clarification in JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225819/try-catch-finally-return-clarification-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the finally block would remove any exceptions being thrown since it would issue a "normal" return.

From the [JLS spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html):

> Abrupt completion of a finally clause can disrupt the transfer of control initiated by a return statement.

and (more relevant in your case):

> Note that abrupt completion of a finally clause can disrupt the transfer of control initiated by a throw statement.

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/48740/34088 The `return` really "overwrites" the `throw`.

Answer (score 4):

There are so many explanations about the finally block in a try-catch-finally statement. Go and search for it.

Quick explanation anyway: The finally block is always run, regardless whether an exception was thrown (and maybe caught) or not. If a finally block terminates in an *unnormal* way (such as itself throwing an excpetion or returning a value) this will always override what was done in the try block or a catch block. That also means that these are got lost.

The conclusion: Never throw an exception ot return a value from the finally block. Only use it for cleaning up processes.

Answer (score 0):

try this.  If you are throwing an exception than there is something wrong with object.  just return it before the catch.

```
try {
    object = (Dev)Class.forName("Dev").newInstance();
         return object;
} catch (Exception e) 
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Devis not available");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning from finally is a bad practice in java.
It may result in many unexpected outputs. Check below link for some of such examples:
http://www.cs.arizona.edu/projects/sumatra/hallofshame/

Anyways found few links related to this finally block, Follow the below links for answers related to that.
[Does finally always execute in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java)
[Returning from a finally block in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088/returning-from-a-finally-block-in-java)