# What is the difference between writing 'return' explicitly and that implicitly in Scala?

Tags: scala

Here's the code in Scala cli:

```
scala> def ff(): Int = try {return 1} finally {return 2}

scala> println(ff())
2

scala> def gg(): Int = try {1} finally {2}

scala> println(gg())
1
```

I want to know why there's distinction whether or not adding the `return` keyword? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return` statement within `finally` conceptually will override the original `return` in `try` block. But if you do not use return, Scala picks the last expression of `try` block as the result of the computation and finally is just executed as side effect and does not have any effect on the result of function. You may take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701793/behaviour-of-return-statement-in-catch-and-finally) as well.